# How to highlight multiple searched words in a document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a file which has words to be searched. I want to highlight those words in the active document.

For example:
style.docx:
Agro commercial
abovementioned
some words
physics
school

Active document:

This is the lines to explain some words such as abovementioned and school. This is the end of the line.

Expected output:
some words , abovementioned, school should be highlighted in the active document.

I have tried the below mentioned code:

```
    Dim docTitle As Document
    Dim docStyle As Document
    Set docTitle = Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\quads\Desktop\stylesheet.docx", ConfirmConversions:=True)
    Set docStyle = Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\quads\Desktop\files\Albala D-ed.doc", ConfirmConversions:=True)

    Dim char As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim count As Integer

    Dim Para As Paragraph

    For Each Para In docTitle.Paragraphs
      If Len(Para.Range.Text) > 0 Then
                ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select

        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
                With Selection.Find
                .Text = Left(Para.Range.Text, Len(Para.Range.Text) - 1)
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            Selection.Find.Execute

        End If
        ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select

    Next Para
```

Also I want to search all of the files in a particular folder ("files") without mentioning the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pasted my answer which highlights multiple searched word (from other file) in yellow in colour.Search word file and file to be highlighted can be chosen using file dialog object.

```
Dim filepath As String
Dim filename As FileDialog
Dim stylepath As String
Dim stylename As FileDialog
MsgBox ("Please choose Style File Name")

Set stylename = Application.FileDialog(filedialogtype:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
If stylename.Show Then
stylepath = stylename.SelectedItems(1)
End If

Set filename = Application.FileDialog(filedialogtype:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
If filename.Show Then
filepath = filename.SelectedItems(1)
End If

Dim range As range
Dim i As Long
Dim arr() As String
Dim docTitle As Document
Dim docStyle As Document
    Set docTitle = Documents.Open(stylepath)
    Set docStyle = Documents.Open(filepath)


arr = Split(docTitle.Content.Text, Chr(13))

For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
Set range = docStyle.range

With range.Find
.Text = arr(i)
.Format = True
.MatchCase = True
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

Loop

End With
Next
```